# List ItemRenderer as Draginitiator in manual Drag & Drop

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, drag-and-drop, flex4

I'm trying to add spark list ItemRenderer as DragInitiator when implementing manual drag & drop functionality. Example below puts whole list as a dragInitiator. Question is how to use Itemrenderer in this case?

```
protected function myList_dragStartHandler(event:DragEvent):void
{
    var dragInitiator:List = event.currentTarget as List;
    var selectedQuery:Object = List(event.dragInitiator).selectedItem;
    var ds:DragSource = new DragSource();
    ds.addData(selectedQuery, "query");
    DragManager.doDrag(dragInitiator, ds, event);
}

<s:List id="myList" y="10" height="273" dataProvider="{sqList}" labelField="desc" itemRenderer="SqItemRenderer"
    dragEnabled="true" dragStart="myList_dragStartHandler(event)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem setting mouseMove handler for my itemrenderer.

```
override public function set data(value:Object):void
{
     if (value != null)
     {
        super.data = value; 
     }
}

protected function itemrenderer1_mouseMoveHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var dragInitiator:IUIComponent = event.currentTarget as IUIComponent;
    var ds:DragSource = new DragSource();
    ds.addData(this.data, "foo");
    DragManager.doDrag(dragInitiator, ds, event);
}
```